# Стоит ли создавать под каждого пользователя новую страницу или обойтись генерацией по Get-запросам?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, вконтакте

Всем привет!
Создаем учебный форум для локальной сети в общаге.
Столкнулись с дилеммой: при регистрации нового пользователя - стоит ли создавать для него web-страницу как отдельный файл типа:
smit.php,
где будут прописаны все функции, которые вызывают данные из баз данных и отображают их на странице и который будет хранится на сервере и вызываться при get-запросе типа:
obshaga.ru/smit
или будет доступен по адресу: smit.obshaga.ru

Или пусть его страница генерируется по ходу пьесы как в vk???

Как лучше-то? :-)

Начальное количество подключений ~300, но планирует вырасти до 8000-12000.

Comment: генерировать лучше - экономия места. нет повторяющихся действий - по сути то на страницах будет одно и тоже, и дублировать их нет смысла. Да и из правил программиста - что повторяется два или более раз следует вынести в функцию.

Comment: Шаблонизатор, несомненно, создаст индивидуальную страницу быстрее, чем дисковая подсистема отыщет готовую среди кучи похожих на диске.

Comment: а phpbb или какое нибудь другое решение для форума не устраивают?

Answer (score 4):

Однозначно лучше делать как в VK и на большинстве современных сайтов. Просто представьте: что если вам когда-нибудь захочется поменять вот эти функции, которые существуют во множестве копий во всех файлах?